# Silverlight DataGrid - Dirty Rows

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a Silverlight DataGrid, for which the user can change values in. I also have a "Save" button. When the user clicks the "Save" button, I want only the rows (items) from the data grid that the user has changed to be saved. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your DataGrid's `ItemsSource` property is bound to a collection of a class called `MyClass`, you could add a `bool` property to `MyClass` called `IsModified`. Then, in the other setters within that class, you could set `IsModified` to `true`. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsModified { get; set; }

    private string _foo;

    public string Foo
    {
       get { return _foo; }
       set
       {
           _foo = value;
           IsModified = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Then, you could use Linq to query the collection of items where `IsModified` is `true` (this code assumes `items` is the collection that is bound to your `DataGrid`):

```
List<MyClass> toSave = items.Where(x => x.IsModified).ToList();
```

Finally, use whatever save method you have to handle each item in `toSave`:

```
foreach (MyClass curr in toSave)
{
    // Save "curr" here...

    // Don't forget to reset IsModified
    curr.IsModified = false;
}
```

Hope this helps.